# How can i start the scatch area for executing queries back to number 1?

Tags: mysql-workbench

[image]

I encircle it in a red ink brush. Everytime I close the queries it will still open after running the workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Either close all editors manually, before you close the connection, or disable saving a workspace snapshot in the MySQL Workbench preferences:

[image]